# Simple way to reuse tailwind component in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS in react. I'd like to know how to reuse a tailwind button style in a simple way, and where to keep the component in the file.

```
   export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <button
              // className='btn-indigo'
              className="py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 focus:ring-opacity-75"
            >
              Button1
            </button>

            <button
              // className='btn-indigo'
              className="py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 focus:ring-opacity-75"
            >
              Button2
            </button>
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`@apply`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) directive:

```css
// do this in your CSS file

.my-btn {
  @apply py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 focus:ring-opacity-75;
}
```

Then in your JSX code:

```js
<button className="my-btn">Foo</button>
```

---

Also you can just create a simple component file:

```
// src/components/MyButton.jsx

const MyButton = ({ children }) => <button className="py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 focus:ring-opacity-75">{children}</button>

export default MyButton
```

In your App file:

```
import MyButton from './components/MyButton'

// ...

<MyButton>foo</MyButton>
<MyButton>bar</MyButton>
```

You'll need to modify `MyButton` if you want to pass other props too. Though, I'ld recommend using a CSS-in-JS library like [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) or [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) instead. There are Tailwind specific alternatives too that may interest you: [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro), [Twind](https://twind.dev/), [xwind](https://github.com/Arthie/xwind).

---

Simplest way - just store the classes in a string.

```
const myBtn = "py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 focus:ring-opacity-75"

// ...

<button className={`${myBtn} some-other-class-specific-to-foo`}>Foo</button>
<button className={myBtn}>Bar</button>
```

You can also use libraries like [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and [clsx](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx) for composing the strings.

Comment: this is not working in my code for some reason.  line 41

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-roman-l69mv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @somniumm you haven't configured postcss in that and also it should be `className="my-btn"` not `className=".my-btn"`. Refer this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: thanks! i'm so lost at configuring tailwind in codesandbox..

Comment: hahaha can't get more hacky than solution 3

Comment: i can see solution 2 and 3 works. but i think solution 1 is probably more standard and easier to do minor customization. could you see if im missing anything else? i followed the tutorial but still can't make the tailwind work. https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-roman-l69mv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @somniumm https://codesandbox.io/s/boxbf

Answer (score 3):

I'm sharing one of my implementations using TypeScript.

You can get ideas of how you can reuse any component with tailwind.
The implementation, naming and pathing usually opinionated.

```
// src/components/atoms/Button.tsx
import {DefaultComponent} from '$types/common';
import {NoopFn, classNames} from '@utils';
import {ReactElement} from 'react';

type ButtonUse = `primary` | `secondary` | `destructive`;
type ButtonSize = `xs` | `sm` | `md`;
type ButtonType = `button` | `submit`;

type ButtonProps = DefaultComponent & {
  size?: ButtonSize;
  type?: ButtonType;
  use?: ButtonUse;
};

const BUTTON_SIZE: {[key in ButtonSize]: string} = {
  md: `text-base px-4 py-2`,
  sm: `text-sm px-3 py-2 leading-4`,
  xs: `text-xs px-2.5 py-1.5`,
};

const BUTTON_COLOR: {[key in ButtonUse]: string} = {
  destructive: `text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700`,
  primary: `text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700`,
  secondary: ``,
};

export const Button = (props: ButtonProps): ReactElement => {
  const {
    className = ``,
    children,
    use = `primary`,
    size = `xs`,
    type = `button`,
    onClick = NoopFn,
  } = props;
  return (
    <button
      {...{onClick, type}}
      className={classNames(
        `inline-flex items-center border border-transparent font-medium rounded shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 justify-center`,
        BUTTON_SIZE[size],
        BUTTON_COLOR[use],
        className,
      )}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

using tailwind and [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
import classNames from "classnames";
function Button({
  children,
  primary,
  outline,
  round,
  // rest will specially good for event handlers mouseover, onclick. 
  ...rest
}) {
  const fullClasses = classNames(
    // you can also pass down specific props, size, border etc
    rest.className,
    "flex items-center px-3 py-1.5 border",
    {
      // in js object key names cannot have "-" so we write inside string
      // if we pass "primary" prop, this value will be evaluated "truthy" so thie key "border-blue-500 bg-blue-500 text-white" will be added to fullClasses
      // if you do not pass primary this key class will not be added
      "border-blue-800 bg-blue-800 text-white": primary,
      "rounded-full": round,
      // later className will override the earlier one. if outline is true earlier bg will be ignored
      "bg-white": outline,
      "text-blue-600": outline && primary,        
    }
  );
  return (
    <button {...rest} className={fullClasses}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```